# Issue with JS alert

Tags: javascript, alert

I am making a simple form that will throw an alert if a 'hidden' field is being filled but I can't see what I am missing or what syntax I have wrong:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.URL/form.php?form=159" id="frmSS159" onsubmit="return CheckForm159(this);">
  <input type="text" name="email" value="Email Address" onclick="this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email Address';" />

  <div style="padding: 5px 0;" aria-hidden="true">
    <input type="text" name="asdf" tabindex="-1" value="" placeholder="If content, alert error">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>




    function CheckForm159() {
    if ($_POST['asdf'] != '') {
        alert("Please type your email address instead of using a form-filler");
    }
    return true;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simplecreatif/3td7oyez/1/)

Comment: What do you think `$_POST` does in *JavaScript*?

Comment: clearly you come from a PHP background - or you're using PHP ... you need to learn to differentiate between the server side code and client side code in a PHP file

Comment: You can not use $_POST in client side scripting. JS does not support this syntax. You should clear your question before ask.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, sorry I've updated the fiddle with Spankajd's code, but still no alert https://jsfiddle.net/simplecreatif/3uf25o15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there is mistake in your code...
you added $_POST which is PHP syntax in JavaScript.

Your updated code...

```
<script> 
   function CheckForm159() {
      var _curValue = document.getElementById('asdf').value;

      if (_curValue  != '') {
         alert("Please type your email address instead of using a form-filler");
      }
      return true;
   }
</script>




<form method="post" action="http://www.URL/form.php?form=159" id="frmSS159" onsubmit="return CheckForm159(this);">
  <input type="text" name="email" value="Email Address" onclick="this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email Address';" />

  <div style="padding: 5px 0;" aria-hidden="true">
    <input type="text" id="asdf" name="asdf" tabindex="-1" value="" placeholder="If content, alert error">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this in an updated Fiddle, but still can't get the alert to pop up (?) https://jsfiddle.net/simplecreatif/3uf25o15/

Comment: hi just add javascript in script tag before form tag

Comment: I have updated answer.. you can directly copy paste code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Just use the onChange function from JQuery. After the input is changed it will show an alert, like so.

```
$("input[name=asdf").change(function(){
   alert("Input value changed!");
});
```

Comment: Jaired Jawed, why you think it should answer? as phillynight doesn't know is $_POST existing in JS or not.

Comment: Is the field in question going to get a change event given that it is not visible? Also, note that the description of StackOverflow's "Javascript" tag says "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected" - there's really no need to bring in jQuery just to bind an event handler.

Comment: The field is like a honeypot so it should never be filled (it will be moved off the screen in production)